# Why are these nested triggers for jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to load two underscore.js templates.  Once the first link is clicked, the skeleton template is loaded.  The first trigger executes the find bind, which executes the loadBookmarks function correctly, but the 'loaded' trigger never fires and the loadFriendBookmarks never executes.  Why is this?  Is there another way to make this happen?

```
$('#bookmarks-link').click(function() {
  $('#bookmarks-count').text("0");
  var skeleton = modalTemplate();
  $('#bookmarks').append(skeleton);
  $('#bookmarks').trigger('skeleton');
});

$('#bookmarks').bind('skeleton', function() {
  $('#bookmarks .thumbnails').loadBookmarks( getBookmarksUrl(1) );
  // If I add an alert('hi') here, it works perfectly.
  $('#bookmarks').trigger('loaded');
});

$('#bookmarks').bind('loaded', function() {
  $('#bookmarks .thumbnails a').each(function() {
    $(this).bind('click', function() {
      $('#bookmarks .bookmarks-table tbody').empty();
      $('#bookmarks .bookmarks-table tbody').loadFriendBookmarks(
        getFriendBookmarksUrl($(this).attr('data-item'))
      );
    });
  });
});
```

So interesting enough, the triggers do work correctly: If I stick an alert in between loadBookmarks and trigger, everything works fine.  If I take it out, then it doesn't.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description and common sense, it sounds like `loadBookmarks()` loads data from a remote source, such as an ajax call. This means that `trigger('loaded')` can fire *before* `loadBookmarks()` has received the data. You can add a callback argument to `loadBookmarks()` and trigger the event there:

```
$('#bookmarks .thumbnails').loadBookmarks( getBookmarksUrl(1) , function() {
  $('#bookmarks').trigger('loaded');
});
```

But this requires your `loadBookmarks` to know to call this function after it receives the data and creates the needed HTML - I can't demonstrate this without seeing the actual code you have in `loadBookmarks`.

---

Additional suggestion: don't bind handlers this way, use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$('#bookmarks').on('click', '.thumbnails a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't want the link to actually be followed, do we
  var url = getFriendBookmarksUrl($(this).attr('data-item'));
  if(url) { // in case it's clicked before the data attribute is set
    var $tbody = $('#bookmarks .bookmarks-table tbody');
    $tbody.empty();
    $tbody.loadFriendBookmarks(url);
  }
});
```

This means that *all* elements matching the selector '#bookmarks .thumbnails a' will call this click handler, even if they were added to the document *after* you called `on`. Meaning you can delegate these events even before calling `loadBookmarks`, removing the need for the `loaded` event at all. Plus, this way you only have one copy of the handler function in memory, as opposed to your `bind` which created a separate copy of the function for each `a` node.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is else where in your code. probably some js error in `loadBookmarks*` functions.

see:

http://jsfiddle.net/BBESV/

triggers work perfectly

Comment: So interesting enough, the triggers do work correctly.  If I stick an alert in between loadBookmarks and trigger, everything works fine.  If I take it out, then it doesn't.  Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like the alert() is creating a delay during which `.loadBookmarks()` finishes loading the data.